# SIGSEGV when adding from memory with NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, segmentation-fault

The [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual vol. 2](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/a4/60/325383-sdm-vol-2abcd.pdf) says that addps can be used with xmm1, xmm2/m128, but when using this instruction with a memory address as second operand it throws SIGSEGV. I don't understand what i'm doing wrong here. I'm using NASM compiler.

```
section .data
uno: DD 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0

section .text
foo:
addps xmm1, [uno]
```

Comment: You need to make sure your memory holding the data is 16-byte aligned for `addps` to function properly. Place `align 16` on the line just before you define `uno`.